# A possible fix to Frege's Basic Law V (and a reference request)?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Consider the formal system of monadic second-order logic (with the usual comprehension axioms for predicates) extended with an $\varepsilon$ operator such that $\varepsilon P$ is an individual whenever $P$ is a (monadic) predicate. The intuition about $\varepsilon P$ in the foregoing is that it is the set of all non-set individuals which satisfy $P$, which I'll call the *natural* extension of $P$; e.g. if the domain of discourse of individuals is $\mathbb{N} \cup \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, $P$ is the predicate "being identical to itself" and $Q$ is the predicate "being distinct from itself", then $\varepsilon P = \mathbb{N}$ and $\varepsilon Q = \varnothing$, but $\varepsilon Q \notin \varepsilon P$, despite $\varepsilon Q$ being an individual identical to itself, since $\varepsilon Q$ is also a set, and therefore not ellegible for being a member of $\varepsilon P$ in the first place. To make this intuition more formal, the following definitions define sethood and set membership within this system:

$$
M x := \exists P (x = \varepsilon P)
$$

$$
x \in y := \neg M x \land \exists P (y = \varepsilon P \land P x)
$$

Natural extensions are distinct from extensions in Frege's *Grundgesetze der Arithmetik* in that they cannot be members of each other, much less of themselves. Natural extensions thus seem to better reflect Frege's intuitions about extensions in the examples given in his work, whereas impredicative extensions, then, appear to be an undesired collateral effect of his naive notion of extensions as it was originally formalized.

The restriction that only non-set individuals may be members of natural extensions of predicates, and the intuition of such natural extensions as precisely the set of such individuals, lends itself to the following principle, which I consider a "fix" of Frege's *Basic Law V* from the aforementioned *Grundgesetze*:

$$
\forall P \forall Q (\varepsilon P = \varepsilon Q \leftrightarrow \forall x (\neg Mx \rightarrow (P x \leftrightarrow Q x)))
\tag{1}
$$

Contrast it with Frege's original *Basic Law V*:

$$
\forall P \forall Q (\varepsilon P = \varepsilon Q \leftrightarrow \forall x (P x \leftrightarrow Q x))
\tag{2}
$$

Under our interpretation of extensions as natural extensions, $(2)$ is clearly more problematic than $(1)$, as it may just be the case that the predicates $P$ and $Q$ are satisfied the same non-set individuals, but not by the same set individuals, which does not justify, then, asserting the distinction of their natural extensions. $(1)$ also seems to avoid the contradictions entailed by $(2)$ (and its corresponding impredicative interpretation of extensions), which I reference from Section 5 of [this entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/) of the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, by Edward Zalta, about Frege's Theorem.

Let $Px$ $:=$ $\exists Q (x = \varepsilon Q \land \neg Q x)$. In the first half of the proof of the first contradiction, one assumes $P(\varepsilon P)$, infers $\forall x (Px \leftrightarrow Qx)$ from $\varepsilon P = \varepsilon Q$ by $(2)$ for some predicate $Q$, and then infers $\neg P(\varepsilon P)$ from $\neg Q(\varepsilon P)$ and $\forall x (Px \leftrightarrow Qx)$, contradicting the assumption. Now, if $(2)$ was replaced by $(1)$, then the first inference would be one of $\forall x (\neg Mx \rightarrow (Px \leftrightarrow Qx))$ from $\varepsilon P = \varepsilon Q$, but since $M(\varepsilon P)$, then it's not possible to make the second inference (assuming the resulting system is consistent), as $\neg P(\varepsilon P)$ does not follow from $\forall x (\neg Mx \rightarrow (Px \leftrightarrow Qx))$ (when instantiated by $\varepsilon P$) and $\neg Q(\varepsilon P)$. In the second half, one assumes $\neg P(\varepsilon P)$ and proves a contradiction from this assumption, but since no contradiction was proven in the first half, all this amounts to a proof of $P(\varepsilon P)$. Since we are thinking of $\varepsilon P$ as the natural extension of $P$, then, letting $Qx$ $:=$ $\neg Mx \land Px$, there exists a predicate $Q$ such that $\varepsilon P$ is also a natural extension of $Q$ (since $P$ and $Q$ satisfy the same non-set individuals) but $\varepsilon P$ is not satisfied by $Q$ itself (since $Q$ is not satisfied by any set individuals). Thus, $\exists Q (\varepsilon P = \varepsilon Q \land \neg Q (\varepsilon P))$, and therefore $P(\varepsilon P)$, has been proven.

The second and more well known contradiction, Russell's paradox, follows from $\forall P \exists y (My \land \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow Px))$ (which itself follows from $(1)$) since it postulates the existence of the Russell set (the extension of the predicate $Rx$ $:=$ $\neg (x \in x)$ such that $\varepsilon R \in \varepsilon R \leftrightarrow \neg(\varepsilon R \in \varepsilon R)$). However, $(2)$ proves instead a weakened form of this theorem, $\forall P \exists y (My \land \forall x (\neg M x \rightarrow (x \in y \leftrightarrow Px)))$, which is to the former theorem as $(1)$ is to $(2)$, and it entails only the existence of the Russell set *as a natural extension*. Since $\forall x (\neg M x \rightarrow \neg(x \in x))$, then the Russell set is simply the set of all non-set individuals (since every non-set individual satisfies $R$) and no set individual is a member of it (since it is a natural extension). Thus, the Russell set it fails to be a member of itself and engender Russell's paradox.

My question is twofold: Has anyone thought about restricting $(2)$ and redefining set membership within Frege's system in this way? And if so, has anyone found a contradiction in the resulting system yet? It seems that this system, if extended with higher-order predicates, is sufficient to interpret Peano arithmetic, since, by defining the cardinal $\#P$ of a predicate $P$ as the natural extension of the higher-order predicate "being a predicate equinumerous to $P$" (effectively as the equivalence class of $P$ modulo equinumerosity), Hume's principle follows by $(1)$ and therefore so do the Peano axioms by Frege's theorem. One could also extend the theory with natural extensions of higher order which admit as members natural extensions of lower order as well as non-set individuals, though the exact formal details of such an extension elude me. Finally, it would also be very interesting to find a set-theoretic model of either of those extended theories, as they currently comprise only a formal language and an axiomatic system without any mathematical semantics.

Comment: There is a huge literature regarding consistent versions of Frege's logic... Sean Walsh, [Fragments of Frege's *Grundgesetze* (2014)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.3861), Kai Wehmeier, [Consistent fragments of *Grundgesetze* and the existence of non-logical objects (1999)](https://www.academia.edu/448789/Consistent_Fragments_of_Grundgesetze_and_the_Existence_of_Non_Logical_Objects) and so on.

Comment: The first "fix" was attempted by Frege himself; see W.V. Quine, [On Frege's Way Out (1955)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2251464) as well as Landini's [The Ins and Outs of Frege's Way Out (2006)](https://philpapers.org/rec/LANTIA-5).

Comment: Also relevant: Philip Ebert & Marcus Rossberg (editors), [Essays on Frege’s Basic laws of arithmetic (2019, Oxford University Press)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Essays_on_Frege_s_Basic_Laws_of_Arithmet/-varDwAAQBAJ)

Comment: A recent interesting viewpoint is J. D. Hamkins'. See his [A Deflationary Account of Fregean Abstraction in Zermelo-Fraenkel ZF Set Theory](http://jdh.hamkins.org/fregean-abstraction-in-zf-set-theory-oxford-november-2021/).